# How to see Description on matchesSafely function when our class is extends with BoundedDiagnosingMatcher in Espresso

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-testing, hamcrest

I've tried many method, but I still cannot see the description inside matchesSafely function. And I've tried to research any related articles but there are still few articles that discuss it.

For make it simple, lets take an example of `WithHintMatcher` class on `androidx.test.espresso.matcher` like shown below:

```java
@VisibleForTesting
  static final class WithHintMatcher extends BoundedDiagnosingMatcher<View, TextView> {
    @RemoteMsgField(order = 0)
    private final Matcher<String> stringMatcher;

    @RemoteMsgConstructor
    private WithHintMatcher(Matcher<String> stringMatcher) {
      super(TextView.class);
      this.stringMatcher = stringMatcher;
    }

    @Override
    protected void describeMoreTo(Description description) {
      description.appendText("view.getHint() matching: ");
      stringMatcher.describeTo(description);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean matchesSafely(TextView textView, Description mismatchDescription) {
      CharSequence hint = textView.getHint();
      mismatchDescription.appendText("view.getHint() was ").appendValue(hint);
      return stringMatcher.matches(hint);
    }
  }
```

### Explanation

---

As we can see, there is a mismatchDescription parameter on matchesSafely function (`mismatchDescription.appendText("view.getHint() was ").appendValue(hint);`).

How do I get that description in the test logs? `"view.getHint() was ..."`, because the logs only shows the description that we defined at `describeMoreTo` function.